# Scheduled jobs are killing Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler

I have four scheduled jobs in spring boot apllication(scheduler) and some more rest APIs, but my spring boot application getting killed sometimes. There is another one spring boot application on same server which is working perfectly fine.

Jobs scheduled at:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * ?")  // Heavy job
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 * * * ?") // Light job
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 3 * * ?")  // Light job
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * ?")  // Light job
```

Application(Scheduler) got killed 3 times in this week at:

```
2018-06-10 01:05:42.305
2018-06-11 02:00:12.165
2018-06-13 12:00:01.603
```

Not getting what is happening? and Why?

Can someone please help me and what solution will be for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of jobs do these scheduled threads do? Define being killed, does that mean u get out of memory error?

Comment: @Indraneel my first job exports CSV file which is bit heavy job but rest of 3 are light jobs which fetch max 500 records.
**KILLED** means process of jar file gets stopped, then I have to restart jar file manually. Also I have handled that condition by **Exception** and **Throwable** but my log is not showing regarding exception or error.
**Note:** There is another jar file which works fine.